# jQuery store multiple divs in array and append the array to a div

Tags: jquery, append

As the title says, I'm trying to select some divs by their id, and then store them in an array, I know I can simply put the variables as parameters separated by comma, but I prefer to store. What I've done is:

```
var nationality = jQuery('#nationality');
var years = jQuery('#years');

var collection = [nationality, years];

jQuery('#mydiv').append(collection);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array, you must iterate the array and perform an action on each object found. This method will work below ->

```
var collection = new Array(nationality, years);
$.each(collection, function(i,v){
  //i = index, so 0,1,2,3,4,5
  //va = value, so <div id="1">1</div>', <div id="2">2</div>'; etc.
  jQuery('#mydiv').append(v);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I like it more than the add method because it doesn't require chaining. But it is very hard to choose the 'answer' when both are the correct answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
var nationality = jQuery('#nationality');
var years = jQuery('#years');

var collection = nationality.add(years);

jQuery('#mydiv').append(collection);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. What if I want to add more variables? Should I repeat the add method, or can I insert multiple parameters in it? I've tried inserting multiple, but with no success.

Comment: If you use `add` then you should chain it like this: `$a.add($b).add($b)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little trick with `apply()`:

```
$.fn.append.apply( $('#mydiv'), collection)
```